# Web update application with Firemonkey on MacOS

Tags: macos, delphi, auto-update, firemonkey

I'm making a Firemonkey application for both Windows and MacOS, and now I'm working on making it able to check online for updates and download the update. I have got it to work on Windows, by renaming the running .exe file, download the new one and then run the downloaded .exe, works as it should.

Now my problem is MacOS, I don't have much experience with MacOS, so I don't really have any idea how I should do this :/
And even less idea as I store somedata files inside the 'program.app' folder.

So I'd really appreciate some help or ideas on how I should try to solve this problem?

Comment: Really no one who knows how to do a auto-update on osx? :(

Comment: Most OSX programs use a (Cocoa) library to auto-update, and I think [Sparkle](http://sparkle.andymatuschak.org) is the most common one.  Have a look at that.  I don't know if you can easily link third-party Cocoa code into a Delphi FMX app, though - you may need to ask another question about doing that.

Comment: Martin, have you found a suitable solution? I have also built an app for Win/OSX and am researching the ways to auto update them. I have also tried replacing the APP folder contents, but it just doesn't feel like an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Apps on OSX are really just a package of files.  If you go into finder on OSX and right click on an app you will see show package contents.  Open that up and you will see the constituent files that make up the "app".  From there you have to decide what you need to replace.

Comment: to update an app, is it enough to just replace the files in the app folder? do you know what files should be updated?

Comment: Depends on the complexity. Here is more detailed info on how bundles or app pkgs work:  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW1.  I have done something similar with Java apps and Python ones including bundling their runtimes so the app is entirely standalone.  The structure is what you need to maintain.  As for what specific files, you will need to determine that based on your own app.  If you want to see what your dependencies are grab a copy of MacDependency